# OrmLite - java 8 date API

Tags: java, ormlite

Am using OrmLite framework for JavaFX application. I've tried searching for serirlizers/deserialozers for java 8 date types but came out empty handed. Perhaps someone also had embarked on same quest in the past and has a solution?

Comment: What date types?  You can also write a custom persister: http://ormlite.com/docs/custom-persister

Comment: @Gray I had came across custom persister capabilities in `ormlite`. I was hoping on some time tested solutions for `ZonedDateTime`, `LocalTime`, `LocalDateTime` etc... Thanks tho, will craft my own.